# Create dataframe in R by selecting columns....but place the results by index

Tags: r, select, indexing

I am trying to create a dataframe by selecting data from several dataframes...basically a simple SQL type exercise but with R.   Sample data is created below.   Dataframe A, and B.   To select from both dataframes and create a new dataframe is straightforward such as:

`AB<-data.frame(COLUMN1=A$ID, COLUMN2=B$ONE, COLUMNS3=B$TWO, COLUMN4=A$JOB, COLUMN5=B$THREE)`

or selecting the data by an index instead of the column name as:

`AB<-data.frame(COLUMN1=A[,1], COLUMN2=B$ONE, COLUMNS3=B$TWO, COLUMN4=A$JOB, COLUMN5=B$THREE)`

What I actually need to do however is create a dataframe and instead of naming the new columns in "AB", I need to designate them by index so they are in the right order.   I tried this as the following but it didn't work obviously.  Any help would be appreciated

`AB<-data.frame([,1]=A$ID, [,2]=B$ONE, [,3]=B$TWO, [,4]=A$JOB, [,5]=B$THREE)`

**SAMPLE DATA**

`A<-data.frame (ID=c("A", "B", "C"), CUSTOMER=c("1", "2", "3"), JOB=c("ONE", "TWO", "THREE"))`

`B<-data.frame (ONE=c("X", "Y", "Z"), TWO=c("10", "20", "30"), THREE=c("SMALL", "MEDIUM", "LARGE"))`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for. Is this what you wanted? `AB <- data.frame(ID = A$ID, ONE = B$ONE, TWO = B$TWO, JOB = A$JOB, THREE = B$THREE)`

Comment: I am quite sure what the desired end result is, a data.frame with the same column names as  original data frames? If that is the case then `cbind()` the 2 dataframes and then rearrange the columns.

Comment: this was a very simple example.   I've actually got several files I'm pulling from based on an RShiny app that makes the query flexible.    However I need instead of "ID" to put A$ID at index position 1, the next one at position 2, next 3...and so on.   I can't figure out how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I think @Dave2e has got it correct. You can select the columns from both the dataframe, `cbind` the result and order the dataframe. This can be done using column numbers or column names.

Using column numbers -

```
index1 <- c(1, 3)
index2 <- 1:3
res <- cbind(A[index1], B[index2])
res <- res[c(1, 3, 4, 2, 5)]
res

#  ID ONE TWO   JOB  THREE
#1  A   X  10   ONE  SMALL
#2  B   Y  20   TWO MEDIUM
#3  C   Z  30 THREE  LARGE
```

Using column names -

```
name1 <- c('ID', 'JOB')
name2 <- c('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE')
res <- cbind(A[name1], B[name2])
res <- res[c('ID', 'ONE', 'TWO', 'JOB', 'THREE')]
res
```

---

Another option would be using `select` -

```
library(dplyr)
res <- bind_cols(A, B) %>% select(ID, ONE, TWO, JOB, THREE)
```

Comment: Thank you for this...  what does "bind_cols" do?  can you expand on that?   What are A and B in this line

Comment: `bind_cols` is `dplyr` function for `cbind` it combines the two dataframe and adds new columns. `A` and `B` are taken from your post.

Comment: perfect - thanks for the response.   So if I had many more I just list them and the select function would recognize which table they came from?   What I am working to duplicate is the SQL type syntax of selecting from a file and related column such as file.column as new column name